# Browser is not opening in blackberry 8900 application

Tags: blackberry

I am embedding browser in blackberry application. In which I open my compny website with some label on top. Its working in simulator, but not on device. In device other  applications  which require browser are running fine.

my device is : 8900

Please let know how I can solve this issue?

Thanks

Shikha

Comment: Not enough details to help you out.  Any exceptions being thrown?  Any code you can show?

Comment: No exception, I am using Sample code"BrowserContentManagerDemo.java" available in JDE folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how its running while adding this string in URL:
";deviceside= false;connectionType = mds-public"

Comment: That is probably going over BIS which might be okay for dev work but if you want to publicly release your app and use BIS then you need permissions from RIM (basically you need to sign up for their Alliance program).

Comment: Is there any link where I can get the details for Alliance program permission. I have signing keys; are these keys are not sufficient to use an app publicly... please suggest

Answer (score 1):

The sample apps all assume that the device is connected via MDS to a BES server, which is true in the simulator (using the MDS simulator).  However when testing on a device you will need to use a different transport if it is not connected to a BES server.  For example, on your 8900 you could use Wi-Fi or Direct TCP (and sometimes WAP2 depending on the carrier).

You'll need to modify the URL passed into Connector.open() so that it has the correct arguments to specify the type of network connection to establish.  See [this thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242) for more information about how to establish an HTTP connection over the various transports.

Comment: thanks, I tried but no success: I appended ";ConnectionUID=WAP2 trans" then ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=WAPtrans Secure" and lot more but getting same issue. Please help

Comment: Trying using just ";deviceside=true" to see if that works (Direct TCP).  You may need to set the APN in your device settings for your carrier.